# Calling a Stored Procedure in Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, stored-procedures, orm

I just started learning hibernate last night and its rather fun. I am some trouble calling a stored procedure as a sql-query with hibernate. I have attached the source and the error, please help me. Thanks :)

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
        "hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
<class name="Example" table="example">
   <id name="user_id" column="id" >
   <generator class="increment"/>
  </id>
  <property name="user_data">
    <column name="data"/>
  </property>
 </class>

<!-- sql-query must be after class --> 

<sql-query name="getRecordsSP" callable="true" >
<return class="Example">
<return-property name="user_id" column="user_id"></return-property>
<return-property name="user_data" column="user_data"></return-property>
</return>
{call getRecords}
</sql-query>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

This is the java file :::

```
    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import org.hibernate.Query;
    import org.hibernate.Session;
    import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
    import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;


    public class SelectProc {


        public static void main(String[] args) {

            Session session = null;
            //String query = "select example.id, example.data from Example example";

            try{

                SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
                session = sessionFactory.openSession();

                System.out.println("selecting records");
                Query q = session.getNamedQuery("getRecordsSP");
        //      Query q =  session.createSQLQuery("call getRecords","",Example.class);

                System.out.print("Done");
                List l = q.list();


                for(Iterator it = l.iterator() ;it.hasNext();){
                    Object row [] = (Object [])it.next();
                    System.out.println(row.length);
            //      System.out.println(row[0]);
            //      System.out.println("ID " + row[0]);
            //  System.out.println("Data "+ row[1]);
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            finally{
                session.flush();
                session.close();

        }
    }
}
```

The error is:::

```
call getRecords}

18:33:41,346  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:38 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
18:33:41,347 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:46 - Column 'id0_' not found.
18:33:41,348  WARN JDBCExceptionReporter:38 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
18:33:41,349 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:46 - Column 'id0_' not found.
18:33:41,349 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:38 - Could not execute native SQL query
java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id0_' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2813)
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:18)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:541)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1201)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.SQLLoader.list(SQLLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.findBySQL(SessionImpl.java:2212)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:85)
    at SelectProc.main(SelectProc.java:28)
org.hibernate.JDBCException: Could not execute native SQL query
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.findBySQL(SessionImpl.java:2215)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:85)
    at SelectProc.main(SelectProc.java:28)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id0_' not found.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1075)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:989)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:984)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:929)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.findColumn(ResultSetImpl.java:1144)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getInt(ResultSetImpl.java:2813)
    at org.hibernate.type.IntegerType.get(IntegerType.java:18)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:62)
    at org.hibernate.type.NullableType.nullSafeGet(NullableType.java:53)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getKeyFromResultSet(Loader.java:541)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getRowFromResultSet(Loader.java:233)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:337)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:167)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:1201)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:1186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.SQLLoader.list(SQLLoader.java:121)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.findBySQL(SessionImpl.java:2212)
    ... 2 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import java.sql.CallableStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;

import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;



public class SelectPP {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Session session = null;
        //String query = "select example.id, example.data from Example example";
        CallableStatement callableStatement = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;

        try{

            SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();

            System.out.println("selecting records");
    //      Query q = session.getNamedQuery("getRecordsSP");
    //      Query q =  session.createSQLQuery("call getRecords","",Example.class);
    //      Query q = session.getNamedQuery("getRecordsSP");

            callableStatement = session.connection().prepareCall("{call getRecords}");
            callableStatement.execute();

            resultSet = callableStatement.getResultSet();

            while(resultSet.next()){
                System.out.println(resultSet.getInt(1));
                System.out.println(resultSet.getString(2));
            }

            //resultSet.

            System.out.print("Done");
            //List l = q.list();


        //  for(Iterator it = l.iterator() ;it.hasNext();){
        //      Object row [] = (Object []) it.next();

        //      Example row = (Example) it.next();
        //      System.out.println(row.getUser_id());
        //      System.out.println(row.getUser_data());
        //      System.out.println(row.length);
        //      System.out.println("ID " + row[0]);
        //  System.out.println("Data "+ row[1]);

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        finally{
            session.flush();
            session.close();
        }
    }
}
```

I basically redesign the input without using hibernate getNamedQuery, but the java.sql class and it worked!!!

Answer (score 3):

According to the documentation, the procedure must return a result set and should be called like this:

```
{ ? = call procedureName(<parameters>) }
```

So try the following instead:

```
<sql-query name="getRecordsSP" callable="true" >
  <return class="Example">
    <return-property name="user_id" column="user_id"></return-property>
    <return-property name="user_data" column="user_data"></return-property>
  </return>
  { ? = call getRecords }
</sql-query>
```

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [16.2.2. Using stored procedures for querying](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/querysql.html#querysql-limits-storedprocedures)

Comment: { ? = call getRecords() } syntax expects a param. The stored procedure does not take in any param.

Comment: @ferronrsmith Then remove the parenthesis?

Comment: Still not working, its kool, i wrote it a different way, thanks anyway