# Get return value (scalar), not result table, from stored procedure using Java and Hibernate

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures, return-value

I'm having a hard time getting the return value (integer) from a stored procedure using Hibernate and Java.

My stored procedure is as follows:

```
create proc dbo.CheckEquipmentAuthorization
    @ReplicaId int
as
    declare @IDAuthType int
    select @IDAuthType = AuthorizationType.IDAuthorizationType from AuthorizationType
    inner join ReplicaAuthorization on ReplicaAuthorization.RefIDAuthorizationType = AuthorizationType.IDAuthorizationType
    inner join Replica_ReplicaAuthorization on Replica_ReplicaAuthorization.RefIDAuthorization = ReplicaAuthorization.IDAuthorization
    inner join Replica on Replica.IDReplica = Replica_ReplicaAuthorization.RefIDReplica
    where Replica.IDReplica = @ReplicaId
    and GETDATE() between ReplicaAuthorization.AuthBegin and ReplicaAuthorization.AuthEnd

    declare @AuthIntValue int
    set @AuthIntValue = 10
    if (@IDAuthType is not null)
    begin
        select @AuthIntValue = AuthorizationType.IntValue from AuthorizationType
        where AuthorizationType.IDAuthorizationType = @IDAuthType
    end
    print @AuthIntValue
    return @AuthIntValue
```

I'm trying to get the return value using:

```
    query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "exec CheckEquipmentAuthorization(:replicaId)")
    .setParameter("replicaId", replicaId);
```

But it seems I can only get a result table using this, and since no result table is generate from my procedure, nor do I want one to be, it fails.

**Is there a way to get that *returned value* using that createSQLQuery() method?**

I'm using Hibernate, Java and SQL Server. The stored procedure is working correctly (I have tested it with a sql client).

Thank you.

Comment: I added my final working solution below to help anyone that has this same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5405830/hibernate-and-stored-procedure). Have you mapped a scalar return type of your stored procedure? And are you translating into that return type?

Comment: I don't believe it is duplicated, I'm trying to get the returned value not the result table. I can't find anything on this subject, only on the result table. What I have found is that usually the returned value is the number of rows in the result table, and it's that returned value that I want to get. It seems really odd that something so trivial can be so hard to do.

Comment: The correct names are Return Code and Result Set, I want the Return Code. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa174792(v=sql.80).aspx)

Comment: Have you defined a result class? Per the linked post/answers there has to be a class you're returning the stored procedure into. Otherwise, you should just get the jdbc connection from the session factory and execute the stored procedure normally.

Comment: I've decided to go with a custom table mapping, and instead of using RETURN @ RetVal, I'll use SELECT @ RetVal AS RetVal and grab it from that table. It just feels odd that there is no quick and easy way to get the Result Code of a query. It's always an Integer, so why there isn't a getResultCode() method in Query leaves me a bit perplex. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

In the stored procedure, I replaced

```
return @AuthIntValue
```

with

```
select @AuthIntValue as RetVat
```

The way I call the stored procedure and transform the result into an object I created.

```
StoredProcResult o = (StoredProcResult)session.createSQLQuery("exec CheckEquipmentAuthorization :replicaId")
.addScalar("retVal", Hibernate.INTEGER)
.setParameter("replicaId", replicaId)
.setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(StoredProcResult.class))
.setCacheMode(CacheMode.GET)
.uniqueResult();

int xpto = o.getRetVal();
```

The StoredProcResult object:

```
public class StoredProcResult {
    public int retVal;

    public int getRetVal() {
        return retVal;
    }

    public void setRetVal(int retVal) {
        this.retVal = retVal;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is very old, but I just found myself faced with the same problem and found a simple solution when working with MS SQL Server.  Modify your original query as follows:

```
query = session.createSQLQuery(
    "declare @result int; exec @result = CheckEquipmentAuthorization(:replicaId); select @result")
    .setParameter("replicaId", replicaId);
```

Now you get the return code as the `query.uniqueResult()` without the need to modify the original stored procedure.  This can be handy when you aren't able (or don't want) to modify the oriignal stored procedure.