# I can not call a stored procedure in java use hibernate and sql-server 2008

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate, stored-procedures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Calling a Stored Procedure in Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3681045/calling-a-stored-procedure-in-hibernate)

I have the following problem:
I can not call a stored procedure in java

what I did was this:

create a class that implements serializable semaforoBO call and add the following

```
@Entity
@NamedNativeQuery(
name="CalculoSemaforo",
query = "exec CalculoSemaforo codigo,fecha",
callable=true,
resultClass=char.class
)
public class SemaforoBO implements Serializable{
//code
}
```

the name of the stored procedure is CalculoSemaforo and has two input variables returning a char.
Then within SemaforoBO there a function that does the following:

```
public char semaforo(){
        DBTenant dbTenant = new DBTenant();
        Session sess;
        try {
            sess = dbTenant.getTenantSession();
            Query query =sess.getNamedQuery("CalculoSemaforo");
            query.setString("codigo", this.codigoarticulo);
            query.setLong("fecha",this.fecha);
            sem = (Character) query.uniqueResult();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            sem = 'x';
        }
        return sem;
}
```

but it gives me a excepccion org.hibernate.MappingException: Named query not known: CalculoSemaforo

any idea how this solution Thanks

Comment: There is similar topic.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10261651/named-query-not-known-for-named-hibernate-query
It can give you an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternative to call the stored procedure using hibernate without map or you have to have to rely on a class to call

```
DBTenant dbTenant = new DBTenant();
        Session sess;
        try {
            sess = dbTenant.getTenantSession();
            Query qry = sess.createSQLQuery("{ call Iturria.dbo.CalculoSemaforo2(?,?) }");
            qry.setString(0, this.codigoarticulo);
            qry.setLong(1, this.fecha);
            sem = (Character) qry.uniqueResult();
        }
        catch(NullPointerException e)
        {
            sem = 'y';
            return sem;
        }
```

thanks for response